# Time series: non-stationary in the short term, but stationary in the long term

Tags: regression, time-series, stationarity

I am working two time series y and x, and I try to fit the linear model y ~ x.
y is stationary, x is not during the modeling period (most recent 50 quarters). But ADF test on the entire series of x, including much longer history than the modeling period, shows x is stationary.

In such case, can I consider x as stationary, and fit linear model y~x without worrying about the spurious relation?

Or x is non-stationary in the model period, so I need to difference the x to make it stationary?

What would be the impact on coefficient estimates and inference?

Any references, thoughts and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you in advance.